# Advance math Stem Homework for Middle School Students in the sixth grade.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am helping out my sixth grader, great niece with her math problem.

> Determine the value of $(-1/2)^2$.

Please help.

Comment: Yes I do Rober Israel.

Answer (score 2):

What’s needed is the general fact that $(-a)(-b)=ab$ for all real numbers $a$ and $b$:

$$\begin{align*}
\left(-\frac12\right)^2&=\left(-\frac12\right)\left(-\frac12\right)\\\\
&=\frac12\cdot\frac12\\\\
&=\frac14\;.
\end{align*}$$

Comment: Thank you so much, I will forward this information to her and provide her with the web site information as well.  Thanks again Brian M. Scott.  Bless you.

Comment: @Shawn: You’re very welcome.

Comment: @Shawn please mark his answer as the correct one if it helped you.